# Entity Tries to Create Child Entity When I just want a Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to figure out how ASP.net Core with Entity Framework Core works when it comes to child entities. Currently, my issue is that I can create a "SomeThing" entity with the Status as a full entity, inserting both, but I cannot figure out how to create a second "SomeThing" that links to the same Status without it throwing an error saying it already exists?

Below are my models and context code:

Main class:

```
public class SomeThing
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SomeThingId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? RequestedDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public bool? Archived { get; set; }

        //Linked items
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required.")]
        [ForeignKey("StatusCode")]
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Child class:

```
public class Status
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The status requires a description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Status()
        {
        }
    }
```

Context:

```
public class OCWRContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SomeThing> WorkRequests { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<SomeThing>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(st => st.SomeThingId);
                entity.Property<int>("SomeThingId")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                entity.Property<byte[]>("Version")
                    .IsRowVersion();
                entity.HasOne(st => st.Status)
                      .WithMany()
                      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Status>(entity =>
            {
                //entity.HasKey(s => s.Code);
                //entity.HasMany(s => s.Code)
                      //.WithOne();

            });

        } 

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connectionString);
        }
    }
```

Am I linking it incorrectly? I cannot find much that makes sense to me on this topic. I come from a mainly JS background and have never used EF before so I'm just running in circles at this point.

My current call to create a "SomeThing" is:

POST

```
{
    "CreatedDate": "2018-06-14",
    "Description": "There's a thing.",
    "CreatedBy": 1,
    "Archived": 0,
    "Status": {
        "Code": "1000",
        "Description": "test"
    }
}
```

Any help in getting me going in the correct direction again is greatly appreciated! If you need any other information from me to help please just let me know. I'm dying to figure this out at this point.

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to create a second "SomeThing" that links to the same Status without it throwing an error saying it already exists

What you're encountering is called [Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities)

> ...sometimes entities are queried using one context instance and then saved using a different instance.
>
> ...In this case, the second context instance needs to know whether the entities are new (should be inserted) or existing (should be updated).

In your case, if the database already has a `Status` with `Code == "A"` then you cannot add a `new Status` with the same `Code`. What you can do without changing your context or models is something like this:

1. `Find` a `Status` with a given `Code`
2. If no `Status` is found, then create a `new Status`
3. Set the `Status` from step 1 or 2 to the `new SomeThing`

Sample code for the steps above:

```
using (var context = new OCWRContext())
{
    string statusCode = "A";

    Status status =
        context.Statuses.Find(statusCode) //Step 1
        ?? context.Statuses.Add(new Status { Code = statusCode, Description = "" }).Entity; //Step 2

    var someThing = new SomeThing
    {
        Status = status, //Step 3
        Description = ""
    };

    context.Add(someThing);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Ah, so it's thinking it's new because it doesn't have some metadata or something that comes from a query? That's interesting. Is there technically a better way to do this if I changed the models/context? They are not locked as this is a new application so I have the ability to change them.

Comment: Yes, think of it like doing `ReferenceEquals` on the `Status` instances so even if two of them have the same `Code`, they are actually referring to different instances.

Comment: OK, I shall test this now that I'm at the office. Thanks for clarifying what was going on!